# Why do business analysts and project managers get higher salaries than programmers?

Tags: management, business

We have to admit that programming is much more difficult than creating documentation or even creating Gantt chart and asking progress to programmers. So for us that are naives, knowing that programming is generally more difficult, why do business analysts and project managers get higher salary than programmers? What is it that makes their job a high paying job when even at most times programmers are the ones that go home late?

**UPDATE**

Excuse my ignorance, from some of the response it seems that the reason why BAs and PMs gets higher salary because they are the ones that usually responsible for the mess programmers make. But at the end of the day, it is programmers that get their hands dirty to fix the mess and work harder. So it still does not make sense.

Comment: They wear better suits :-)

Comment: Bigger salary in america has absolutely nothing to do with skill.  More you are liked, and the more you play the politics game, the more you get paid.   Programmers are usually logical, intelligent, individuals, who tell it like it is.  Executives hate that.

Comment: "...the ones that goes home late..." Not to come across harsh but this sounds like a personal issue you need to address. If putting long hours in is how you define your worth to the company then some serious personal analysis needs to be done.

Comment: @Aaron: My last sentence was more to be ironic and flippant.

Comment: Reminds me of Dilbert's Salary Theorem: http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~frome/dilbert.html

Comment: I will mention that the PM and business analyst on the main project I am working on put in way more hours than I do. There isn't enough money in the universe to pay me to do their jobs.

Comment: They do? Most jobs I've seen for business analysis and PMPs are at or below the average for programmers... more so compared with average salaries for engineers.

Comment: Do they? John Carmack used to have a Ferrari, now he has a Tesla Roadster I think..

Comment: Most "old time" management still see programming as simply a type of manufacturing.

Comment: Easy: you would have to pay me a hell of a lot more to do that kind of work than the work I love.

Comment: salary is inversely proportional to the knowledge ;-)

Comment: Well if you still count the likes of Larry Page, Sergey Brin and Mark Zuckerberg as programmers (they were so in the beginning, and are still active in the technical sides of their businesses AFAIK), then the top earners are programmers. So there seems to be a gap between the top and mid/lower levels :)

Comment: Programmers usually lack the hubris to demand more, because for them money is just nice. For managers money is whole life.

Comment: Funny, in 9 days I'll stop being a BA and start being a programmer. This move comes with a 43% pay raise.

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP has his mind made up. Why ask the question then?

Comment: Programmers are the slaves, executives are the slave owners :) It's not about skill or hard work. It's about politics and power. See "why is Paris Hilton paid more than most programmers when clearly she is a stupid ****". There is no justice in the world.

Comment: The moment you want to become legally responsible for your code, will be the moment you get paid more. :)

Comment: @MVCylon I disagree with your premise.  I think being sociable and having good demeanor are valued skills that employers are willing to pay for.  When you look at most very highly compensated software developers they not only have technical chops, they have 'soft skills' as well.

Comment: More [perceived] responsibility = more money.

Answer (score 388, accepted):

**Whether project managers get higher salaries than programmers and business analysts at all exist as a class depends squarely on the software world you live in.**

[A simple answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45776/why-do-business-analysts-and-project-managers-get-higher-salaries-than-programmer/45780#45780) to this question would be "because in our societies, we still think the salary is bound to the position in the hierarchy." But this answer whilst reflecting the fact that people are paid based on their perceived value doesn't explain why PM and BA are on top of the hierarchy in many software organisations and why the management goes for hierarchy in the first place as a structure of choice for software project team. These are the two questions that seems to be really worthy asking.

Broadly speaking there are two categories of software making organisations. I will call them Widget Factories and Film Crews.

Widget Factories are born out of management school of thought revolving around [motivation Theory X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_X_and_theory_Y) proposed by McGregor: rank employees are lazy and require constant control and supervision, jobs are held in the name of a pay check, managers are always able to do their subordinates' jobs to the higher or, at least, same standard. This thinking lands to a natural idea that the entire team can easily be replaced with and represented by the manager alone - after all everyone else on the team is either easilly replacable or there just to enhance manager's ability to complete tasks. Hence the hierarchy as a structure and rather horizontal job roles.

Widget Factory management operates on the assumption that software can be manufactured out of a specification prepared by a business analyst through a clearly defined process run under the close supervision of a project manager. The manufacturing is taken care of by staffing the project with enough qualified yet interchangeable programming and testing resources. Work is driven by a prearranged budget based on the initial business case prepared by PM and BA.

Management that runs a Widget Factory is easy to spot just by paying attention to the way these people talk. They are likely to be on about resources (including when referring to team members), processes, operating efficiency, uniformity, repeatability, strict control over use of resources, clear-cut job roles and defined process inputs and outputs. They'd casually mention the actual factory metaphor when trying to convey the image of the ideal software development operation as they see it.

Then there are Film Crews. They are based on the notion that people are intelligent, self-motivated, work really hard and enjoy their jobs as much as kids enjoy playing. Film Crews recognise that due to specialisation individual contributor abilities may by far surpass the abilities of people organising, co-ordinating and directing the work. Since manager can no longer substitute for everyone the hierarchical structure just doesn't work that well - people have to co-operate within a much flatter and complex formation to get things done. Jobs roles themselves tend to be much more vertical - start to finish - and involve a broader variety of skills. This management thinking is underpinned by [McGregor's Theory Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_X_and_theory_Y).

A director of a Film Crew knows that her vision for a piece of software can only come true should she be able to assemble a great crew, fascinate the imaginations and help the team to gel and work together. Her role is to inspire, guard the vision, provide direction and focus the efforts. Every single person matters because "director" believes that software results from combination of worldviews and abilities of all participants and a unique way the group carries out the work together. Everyone recognises from the onset the importance of getting the stars to join the crew – star performers increase every chance for success. Vision drives budget and attracts funding.

**When it comes to compensation** Widget Factories deem that the most value is derived from the work done by project manager and business analyst who reside on the top of the hierarchy and have to be compensated accordingly, the rest of the team doesn’t matter that much as long as they’ve got the right qualifications to convert requirements into working code. PM and BA work hard to maintain their position on top of the pack by restricting free access to the sources of project information to the rest of the team. Without formal access to the primary info sources the team struggles to make any value judgements or come up with good solutions, programmers are relegated to taking orders from above and working on the problem as defined by PM and BA. This situation further reinforces the Widget Factory notion that programmers are akin to factory shop floor workers only capable of mechanically carrying out though technically complicated, but nonetheless standard tasks.

In a stark contrast Film Crew acts as a more egalitarian formation; members are given unrestricted access to primary information, encouraged to form value judgements and are free to select a course of actions to fulfil and contribute to the vision. Leadership structure is based on ability rather than a specific role within the team. Compensation reflects how desirable getting a specific person to take part in the project, it often tied to the perception of how much more valuable the end result will become if that person can be convinced to devote their energy to creating that piece of software.  In this environment the role of a project manager becomes less prominent as he is unlikely to be the creative leader; the role comes down mostly to administrative support and external relations. Business analyst’s duties are partly replaced by the role of visionary (I called her earlier “a director”) and partly absorbed by other team members.

Now, it won’t come as a surprise that most in-house software development teams and some consultancies are run as Widget Factories relying on a process to produce consistently boring software; it is these environments where project managers and business analysts are routinely paid more than programmers based on the assumption that they bring the most value with the environment structured accordingly making it difficult for programmers to prove the management wrong.

Successful software companies tend to adopt Film Crew viewpoint, any other philosophy would hinder their ability to attract great people that they rely on so much to produce great software. It’s unlikely you’d ever see a business analyst role in that setting and project managers are less prominent and routinely get paid less than great programmers.

Comment: we need a list of 'Film Crew' software makers :)

Comment: excellent outline of the situation

Comment: Excellent summary. An important point to mention is that in most companies, software development is treated as a cost (same as, say, paying a utilities bill), and not as a core investment.

Comment: dbkk, absolutely working in a cost centre has a big impact on how the work is done. Although many companies do capitalise money spent on internal software projects rather than treating it as an expense which possibly makes the situation even worse in the long run because many internal development projects produce software worth less than the money spent!

Comment: Good answer! You gave a good picture of two different kinds of orgs and portrayed how they view the same job. A software developer need to choose the organization where his contribution will be important and valuable piece in the output. Just as a sound engineer/music director is to a Movie.

Comment: Dude, this is a brilliant response.  The Film Crew analogy works so well.  I worked for a Film Crew for 9 years before it got bought by a widget factory, after which I only lasted 8 months.  I then started my own software development business and we are so a Film Crew.  I think you've just given me the analogy I need to communicate how we work.  Thanks!

Comment: Sadly I know which category I am in.

Comment: Great analogy. Thanks. _Film Crew_ sounds like an Agile type company.

Comment: Actually, if Film Crews were better than Widget Factories then today there would be no more Widget Factories since they would have been replaced by Film Crews. Maybe it's a process so in a 100 years, there will be only Film Crews..

Comment: Sadly, I'm in a Widget Factory that fancies itself to be Film Crew.... utterly frustrating.  Great answer

Comment: BTW, you can spot a previsible movie just from the poster. If the producer name is bigger than the director then it won't be a great movie. You may have some fun, but it won't be something you can call art.

Comment: Then why do so many large, well-known, software companies choose to be Widget factories?  They certainly attract some of the best talent and have products that dominate the market.

Answer (score 275):

Because in our societies, we still think the salary is **bound to the position in the hierarchy**.

The analysts or project managers are higher in the hierarchy, so they should be paid more.

Let me tell you a real story that illustrate why this is a problem.

> A good friend started as a programmer in a big hospital. Thanks to his hard work and dedication, he quickly became Oracle DBA, which was a critical position in a company where data is both sensitive and valuable.
>
> The hospital worked with levels. Levels are bound to your position in the hierarchy, legacy and diplomas.
>
> My friend got a proposal to become DBA in another company that didn't use salary levels. His salary could be increased a lot. Because he liked and respected the hospital he worked for, he decided to talk to the boss, asking for an increase.
>
> The boss refused. It was impossible because of the levels and the unions would not let that happen.
>
> My friend left.
>
> The hospital eventually hired an external consultant (not bound to levels) and posted a job on their website. The consultant did not know anything about the infrastructure in place, so his learning curve was huge. The hospital lost lots of money because of that.
>
> The hospital did lose a lot more. The external consultant was paid as much as 5 times what my friend asked for, and they couldn't find a qualified employee to replace him.
>
> That was almost three years ago. My friend is still at his new place and climbing the hierarchy ladder very fast doing what he loves.
>
> The hospital is still paying 5 times more.

**IMHO, salary should be relative to the value you provide to the company**.

**UPDATE**: When you move higher in the hierarchy, there is the leverage effect occurring. So in fact, you are paid for the value you bring. But brilliant programmers that are 10x more productive should be paid 10x more, regardless their position in that hierarchy (usually at the very bottom). That's what I wanted to highlight.

Comment: What a wonderful anecdote.

Comment: You are correct - salary should be relative to value. Frequently this is not the case. In some small private companies where everyones salary is kept secret (and individually negotiated) then only the big boss knows who is paid what. And sometimes in those places the salary is relative to value, and some supervisory people get paid less than the really clever people doing the work. This does not happen often, of course.

Comment: Pierre, sounds like public sector in the UK!

Comment: @quickly_now: Or two people doing the same job get paid vastly, vastly different amounts.

Comment: The employee could perhaps have proposed to work as an external consultant?

Comment: @Thomas: yes I remember I suggested it, but he was not very interested (fear of losing of his security, which is IMHO an illusion), and that would not solve the budget problem of the hospital.

Comment: Pierre 303, great answer, still doesn't explain why PM and BA are on top of the hierarchy in some software organisations and why the management go for an hierarchy as a structure.

Comment: @Totophil: it's obvious for PM, but I agree that BA should be in the team and not on top or on the side.

Comment: @Pierre 303 "...10x more productive should be paid 10x more..." And your production metric is?

Comment: @Aaron: Like this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26596/metric-by-which-to-hold-developers-accountable/26602#26602

Comment: @Pierre 303 That's pretty vague. Production has to equate to quality at some stage. Bugs may not surface until months down the road...but was that programmer still 10x more productive? In addition using what the customer paid as a gauge of production implies that a sales rep who low balled a bid to get the work would then put an enormous amount of pressure on the programmer to remain productive (under your definition of production); simply based on the bid the sales rep placed in front of the customer.

Comment: @Aaron: service & product companies are managed differently. I'm in a product company.

Comment: In fact, that's a great reason to hire great programmers. They are 10x more productive, and you pay, what, 4-5x more than the base programmer.

Comment: nice history, but i think its off topic. The question was not "how it should be", but why its how it is.

Comment: @IAdapter: Because in our societies, we still think the salary is bound to the position in the hierarchy.

Comment: 10x productivity doesn't have to equate 10x salary if the programmers at the bottom end of the scale are overpaid, which they usually are. My experience is that there are programmers who get paid a full wage that add negative value to a company's bottom line (they produce less than they cost) but manage to survive through corporate inertia.

Comment: @dr. evil: because he wanted to keep his employee security.

Comment: Well said! these kind of explanations grab the minds of readers than technical jargon :P

Comment: do you have any measurement for knowing the productivity of a programmer? (its a millions and millions of dollar question).

Comment: @bold: I don't measure programmers individually. I measure the whole team. But if you really want to measure programmers, it's sadly very possible.

Comment: On the update it is said , a programmer that produce 10X as much should get 10X as much. 

How do you know the quantity each produced?

Comment: @bold: I know my people

Comment: When a programmer's productivity drops off (say due to external life events -- new babies, death of loved ones, something) should that programmer start making less money?

Comment: This is not entirely right. In a free market economy salary (ie. cost of labor) is (theoretically) directly defined by supply and demand. This means that if you have a skill that is more valuable than someone else's you should be paid more. The market economy intrinsically correlates value with salary, because all companies want the most valuable employees and thus increase salaries by fighting for those valuable people (see Google's recent fight to retain its employees). Of course the market is not perfect: people don't want to move, managers don't understand this, etc...

Comment: @o1iver: I'm not talking about skills, but value. Skills is one useful component to provide value in a market in high demand.

Comment: @Pierre 303: but what brings value apart from skills (which include technical ability, social skills, humor, past experience (at current company), etc...)?

Comment: This is a terrible anecdote.  The same exact point could be made from the position of a sole programmer who codes themselves into an obfuscated corner and then demands a 500% raise.

Comment: @o1iver: unfortunately, developers are generally not the best when it comes to selling themselves.

Comment: @o1iver: The boss define what value is. That's why one individual can really suck in one job, and be brilliant in another.

Comment: The real answer is this:  Supply and demand.  There are many, many more good developers than there are good managers.

Comment: @Nick - perhaps you should have said *adequate* developers. I have worked with hundreds of developers and good developers are very rare indeed. Good managers are a dime a dozen, as long as that person wants to be a manager. Most bad managers become managers because they want the higher pay but they don't like the work so rather than manage they stay developers that are tasked with manager duties. Of course they end up doing a lousy job at both positions.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I agree entirely, thats one of the reasons I thought about when I wrote the market is not perfect (not enough characters). I guess that this is where managers get a lot of the extra money, they are a lot better at negotiating. And maybe, just maybe, programmers don't make as much because you can "bribe" them more easily. I think I would myself take a slightly lower salary if I get to have a super cool 43-display 3D computer setup to program on :-)

Comment: This sounds similar to how Fog Creek pays its employees: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000038.html - Is there anything that Fog Creek does bad?

Comment: @iconiK: I'm sure Joel is smart enough not to use his levels against himself

Comment: It's funny how everybody's talking about metrics for measuring developers, but no one mentions metrics for measuring *managers* - even if you consider both metrics to be similarly vague (and IMHO measuring managers is much harder), it doesn't explain why the premise is that managers should be paid more

Comment: @ohadsc: managers should be paid more because, 1. programmers only respect a manager that can code, 2. a programmers doesn't get promoted to management unless he's good, 3. a good programmer is likely already on the higher end of the salary scale, 4. a good programmer doesn't want to do management, and certainly not for the same pay, so 5. a good programmer will only do management for more money. It's really quite logical.

Answer (score 84):

They take more **risks** than programmers do. They have to make decisions based on whatever information we gave them, and then face the stakeholder's harsh criticism when their expectations aren't met. Part of the pay package compensates for this risk.

Another factor may be the years of experience needed to prepare a project manager who can plan, estimate and mitigate properly. In some sense, a nuanced project manager is **trained through failures, making it an expensive-to-acquire skill**. Once reached the level of seniority, a company may not be willing to let go of such valuable personnel.

Edit:

There are more kinds of risks than financial or physical harm. For example, consider the risk of being reprimanded by the manager or the customer. Although no actual harm is done, it is still undesirable enough that we adapt our behaviors in order to avoid this kind of outcome. However, managers have to make good decisions all the time, and has to balance different kinds of risks in the interest of the company, not according to personal preference.

Comment: "They take more risks than programmers do." Like what? I've yet to see a project manager or indeed any manager suffer any serious hardship because of a bad decision. (In the software industry, that is.)

Comment: @9000 Bad project managers on the other hand are very easy to find and they command higher salaries too.

Comment: Wow. I think that @rwong, @9000, and @biziclop all make compelling arguments. This answer and its associated comments are a really good sidebar to the original question.

Comment: @biziclop: alas, same is true for bad vs good programmers and generally for any bad %s trying to impersonate as a good %s and command an equal salary.

Comment: Facing stakeholder's harsh criticism is not really an economic risk and is not worth much of extra reward, it's part of being held accountable for a string of bad decisions taken or hiding true information about work progress from stakeholders. A programmer faces a similar risk should they be caught out knowngly producing extreemly poor non-functioning code whilst reporting "all green". In most organisations PM's are not critised for not delivering that is deemed impossible.

Comment: Getting fired for making the wrong decision and walking away with a multi-million dollar severance package sure sounds horrible!

Comment: @biziclop: That makes it much easier for the hiring organization to justify giving them the boot.

Comment: @Wooble, There are may be less than 1% of managers who gets such a treatment. Most of the guys get canned without second thought.

Comment: This is not quite true. What's the worst consequence of the _risk_ they're taking? Losing their job probably? So by saying "higher risk" you probably meant "losing their job more easily." So it goes like "because they lose their jobs more easily, they're paid higher when they're still hired." Is that true in general? I guess not.

Comment: @biziclop: To be fair, bad programmers tend to stick like shit and just fill rank positions without hardship of their own either. And there a lot more of them.

Comment: As opposed to the decades of experience a great programmer needs to have? Risk? When things fail it always falls on engineering. The PM just passes on the blame. What B.S.

Answer (score 80):

Programming may be more difficult by some measure, but it's also more pleasant. You just sit there and solve the nice programming puzzle while managers deal with all kind of crap between their subordinates, their clients, their own bosses and stakeholders. That's why so few sane people actually want to be managers, so you have to compensate for that by paying more.

**Programming is more difficult, but managing sucks more.**

One way to think what's someone's value to a company is to imagine what it would be like if that person left the company. Usually managers turn out to be more valuable in that sense than programmers. [James Gosling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling), the creator of Java, recently left Oracle. One could think it's a huge loss, but guess what? Actually it doesn't matter. It hardly has any effect on Java or on Oracle. Dogs bark, but the caravan goes on.

By the way, I (seriously) think that dustmen and cleaners should be paid way more than programmers. Cleaning other peoples' litter is a job that sucks *and* is indispensable.

Comment: @Joonas - "....think that dustmen and cleaners should be paid way more than programmers" <-- You're going to need to explain that one to me! WTF?

Comment: It is certainly true that cleaning is a tough job physically. Still, there are way more people who are capable of doing a decent job as a cleaner than there are decent programmers. So the market values good programmers higher.

Comment: "Dogs bark, but the caravan goes on." @Joonas Why such string sentiments? Are you a PM? :)

Comment: @james: Those people are doing stuff that's absolutely indispensable. If you had to choose, would you rather live in a world without software, or in a world with dirt, litter and garbage all around? I would choose the "without software, with garbage management" option, but your mileage may vary of course.

Comment: @Mayank: No, I'm just a humble programmer, who thinks that programmers generally value themselves way too high :-)

Comment: @Péter Török: Granted, that's how markets work. Although, there aren't many people who are capable of doing a decent job as a chess player, but I don't think that even those few people get paid too well.

Comment: @Joonas, fair enough, the other side of the equation is that market demand for programmers is way higher than that for chess players. As a side remark, Big Blue getting on par with the best chess players in the world may have significantly reduced the myth and glamour surrounding top chess players. OTOH the guys who made this possible are *programmers* ;-) So in a way, we may be seen as the wizards of our time, achieving (to the layman) incomprehensible magical stuff by typing on humble keyboards. Also, many of us having some quirky habits like all decent wizards should ;-)

Comment: @Joonas - I agree with the indispensable part, but there are no skills to it, every person on the planet could do it, hence low wages. Not everyone can do programming. The harder the skill  the more higher the pay. That is how the world works.

Comment: @jpartogi: Programmers don't need to stand the stink and strain their muscles to make code. It's a comfy job, as we know.

Comment: *Usually managers turn out to be more valuable in that sense than programmers.* - Hmm... Really? I'm not sure if I agree with you. Nevertheless, I gave you a +1 because your answer was otherwise solid.

Comment: Okay, so Gosling left Oracle and you didn't notice anything bad happening to Oracle.  How many managers left Oracle without anything much bad happening?  If Larry Ellison left, would Oracle shrivel and die or would Oracle keep going in much the same manner (with possible longer-term changes)?

Comment: I disagree with both notions that programming is more difficult than management and that management is more daunting job than programming: both involve defining, understanding and solving problems, albeit in different planes. Coming up with and selling a vision worthwhile pursuing (such as building the iPhone) or turning around a failing company (such as limping giant Nokia) are incredibly difficult yet interesting management jobs.

Comment: Sitting in front of a legacy system with a design that evolved into a horrible mess and trying to create a quick patch for the next release without breaking any more code is a daunting yet common programmer task that really sucks. There are thousands of happy managers and thousands of miserable programmers. So your answer doesn’t really explain the difference in the earnings.

Comment: This is like the baseball stat [Value Over Replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_over_replacement_player). It's not how much the player contributes to the team, it's how much better the player is than an average substitute.

Comment: @mmyers:  It's also a matter of how many people you can field.  It's easier to get more productivity by adding programmers than more efficiency by adding managers.  (Similarly, the value, in dollars, of a shortstop's defense is based on the fact that you can't field two cheap shortstops without pulling a fielder from somewhere else.)

Comment: I see no correlation whatsoever between pay (cost to company) and the comfort level of the job.

Comment: the chess analogy is lame. I play chess and I can tell you it's much harder than programming. Chess doesn't pay because it has no business value whatsoever.

Comment: @VladGudim +1M Well Said. Legacy systems and their patches -  a developers nightmare. Bulls Eye.

Comment: Waooo, I cannot believe this was epic HOT topic after a year.

Answer (score 71):

Reducing management to creating charts and writing documentation is like saying that programming is typing.

To each their own, but for me programming is much easier than managing people.

Comment: This is a programming forum, so most people here will find programming easier than management.  Overall, without the selection bias, I'd suspect most people can manage better than they can program.

Comment: I disagree.  Good managers are few and far between, just like good programmers.

Comment: If you can't type you can't be a good programmer.

Comment: @Woo4Moo you should consider the ableism of that statement.

Comment: @Dima:  Good managers and good programmers are rare.  Mediocre managers are easier to get than mediocre programmers.  Not that long ago in the US, the way to advance was to be sufficiently good at doing X to be promoted to supervising or managing X, based partly on the idea that any reasonably able person could manage.

Comment: @Woo4Moo actually if you can't think logically you can't be a good programmer. There are quite a few disabled programmers now that use Dragon Naturally speaking et all.

Comment: @Woo4Moo - adaptability tools mean typing is a minor part of the  job. Thinking logically and creatively at the same time is not.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that good managers are harder to find than good programmers. I've worked with hundreds of programmers and have only come across 3 or 4 that I would rate as good, and yet I can think of dozens of good managers that I've worked with.

Answer (score 36):

Everyone here is focused on the negatives. I've never met a programmer that likes office politics and good managers shield you from that sort of garbage. Having interacted with a lot of people at our main client, half of them are insane and I'm glad to have my PM there to soak up that insanity for me. If they pay them a lot, that's fine. He or she needs it for the inevitable therapy.

Comment: You don't have to like office politics to be able to play the game effectively.

Comment: I know, but I prefer someone else play the game so I can write code.

Comment: I like to play games, but not with other people.

Comment: The hardest thing about being a BA is making sense of the contradictory requirements.  Every stakeholder has a different idea of what is required.  Then the big bosses are the most delusional and insane.  Extracting requirements that the programmers can put up with and produce something useful is enough to drive the BA to drink and expensive recreational pharmaceuticals.

Comment: Yes but the bad managers just push the office politics from the client straight to the developer, which kinda negates the point.

Comment: @CyberED I'm a dev that occasionally does some BA work for my company. I know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 20):

It's arguable of course, but a significant reason behind this is that **they carry the responsibility of the project** if it fails, not the programmers. They might give you a earful for cocking something up, but **they face criticism** from even higher powers. They're the ones in charge of **planning and estimation**.

Managing requires a very **multi-faceted skill-set**: people skills, leadership, ability to estimate costs and time. To do all this they also need to still be in touch with your side of the things (ie have some clue of what you're doing, technically speaking) or be very good judges of character.

If requirements were not defined correctly, it's their fault.

If test plans were not defined correctly, it's their fault.

If you go on vacation or break your leg or get wasted on a Saturday night or leave without giving enough notice and they have to find a replacement or <some reason here> and you cannot get to do your work and the product doesn't get delivered (on time or at all), **it's still their fault**.

Also note that when I mean they carry the responsibility, **it impacts people above and below them**. If they screw things up, it might be your team's jobs that are on the line. That's also the kind of **pressure** you get paid for.

*PS: Plus, I don't know if I would say that programming is harder than doing Gantt charts  (to reuse the example you mention). I don't know about you, but I find programming (in general, for 80% of the stuff you need to do in the industry) fairly easy. If you screw something up, you can fix it. If your boss screws up his gantt chart or his cost estimation, now that's going to be a much bigger issue than inverting a `!= null` for a `== null`. Small mistakes matter on a wider scale for them. Most of the time, of course if you screwed up a test like this in an embedded medical application that went live, that's also a big problem. But they'll get more problems than you!*

Comment: They may carry most of the responsibility (most, not all), but they won't carry most of the blame.

Comment: @Karpie: Of course programmers might get to be held accountable for mis-haps, but managers will carry most of the blame. Maybe not in your yes, but to the upper management of the company (or its stakeholders), the programmers aren't to blame. It's the people managing them who are. Of course, I can understand your point (and of the person saying that "salaries are bound to the position in the hierarchy"), and there are some companies that get away with idiots managing teams and laying blame on others. It's not what it's supposed to be, and in my experience isn't the general case.

Comment: @Karpie: And I do know that in some people's eyes I might be the Devil's advocate here, but while I would like that salary rewards the added-value brought by a person to a company, I don't know that many companies that would be able to run only with programmers. Some staff bring indirect value, and it's harder to quantify. And it's often way too easy to consider that they are just lying around doing nothing, pointing fingers and playing a blame game when they may well be under a lot more pressure than you might think.

Answer (score 19):

**[Supply and demand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand)** is an economic model of price determination in a market. It concludes that in a competitive market, the unit price for a particular good will vary until it settles at a point where the quantity demanded by consumers (at current price) will equal the quantity supplied by producers (at current price), resulting in an economic equilibrium of price and quantity.
The four basic laws of supply and demand are:

- If demand increases and supply remains unchanged then higher equilibrium price and quantity.
- If demand decreases and supply remains unchanged then lower equilibrium price and quantity.
- If supply increases and demand remains unchanged then lower equilibrium price and higher quantity.
- If supply decreases and demand remains unchanged then higher price and lower quantity.

**In this case, one reason is that there are too many developers.**

Comment: There are many low-level developers, but competent programmers are needles in the haystack

Comment: That's certainly the theory of how salaries are supposed to work in a market economy. Your salary is not determined by the value you bring to the company, but by the marginal cost of replacing you. The trouble is there are no truly free markets. Nepotism, cronyism, rent-seeking, and asymmetry of knowledge, are endemic. In theory, organizations that fall into these inefficiencies should be put out of business by ones that don't, but when almost everyone does it ...

Comment: Or perhaps--it's difficult to determine the quality of a programmer, and so the market *appears* flooded, but the majority of the supply side is actually unsuitable. This would explain a lot of code I've seen...

Comment: This is the real answer, despite all the nice answers above.

Comment: Agreed, this answer explains by far the most important component of the salary difference.

Comment: It's relatively easy to determine the value of a PM or BA.  PM's get projects done on time, BA's don't get customers screaming, projects don't fail up front. Programmers are a Market For Lemons. It takes years to discover how poor code,by then they've moved on. Average programmer tenure is 18 months, it takes 2-3 years to find problems. (Is this an application of Nyquist's theorem?) A project can complete with high technical debt without it being noticed.There is also an abundant supply of cheap programmers who write rotten code. Accurate programmer valuation is difficult, replacement cheap.

Comment: Note that the market is not symmetric. An employer have a choice of thousands of programmers. A programmer have a choice of just several employers. The losses of an employer due to one programmer are negligible in comparison with the total capitalization or revenue of a company. The losses of a programmer are enormous - it usually takes several month to change a job, so it is like percent or several percents of the only resource of the programmer - his lifetime. You see that the managers have more power here since they are in a position to make their replacement more expensive.

Comment: If this was true then 3 programmers hired at the same time woudl make the same salary and that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 17):

I've shifted between developer and PM roles throughout my career. I have developers on my project making twice as much as I do and others who are making half. The high wage earners are being paid what they are because:
A) They are "rockstar" developers.
B) They interact with the customers, explain the product in a way that is easy for the customers to understand, and are personable.
C) They direct teams of developers who work on multiple projects.
D) They are always available and eager to please.

They perform the roles of a developer, PM, and BA in varying capacities. Generally, if you're spending 90% of your time heads down, cutting code then you're not incredibly valuable and likely are easily replaceable. If you want to make more money then you need to take on more responsibility... and probably have to find another company that will pay you more.

Answer (score 11):

The rationale is that a project manager's area of responsibility (often) is to deliver the whole project on time, with acceptable quality, within a planned budget. There's often a lot of money at stake, so naturally good project managers often have higher compensation than programmers.

However I don't feel that business analysts, on average, earn a significantly higher salary than programmers. And it's my feeling that it is becoming less common that salary level in a company is determined by hierarchy and not by an employee's value.

Comment: i think the reason for it is that a lot of BA's are promoted from common programmers. In many companies promotion does not mean more money.

Answer (score 10):

My experience might be different (or I'm living in an different universe with distorted laws of physics), but most business analysts and project managers (not **program** managers, but **project** managers or PMPs) positions I've seen are at or slightly below the average salary of programmers.

The salary gap begins to widen more when compared to the average salary of software engineers (on the software engineer's favor). The gap is even more when compared to senior EE or senior software engineers. Almost no senior business analyst or senior PMP will make the same as a senior EE or senior/principal software engineer.

A program manager, however (which is not the same as a PMP), that person will make a lot more than anyone else (and the reasons should be obvious.)

---

The thing that bugs me the most when I see these complaints about salaries is that as programmers (specially as junior/entry level programmers in the enterprise), we are (or were not) that special. There is nothing really in an entry level programmer right out of school that deserves a rocket scientist salary. **No**.

All of us that work on software started from zero. We all did.

And **IF** we are really honest, we know well that we didn't know crap. Being able to complete our undergrad CS course load is just the starting point. It does not make us that special or ZOMG!!!! uber-Einstenian. Really, NO!

And yet (and thanks to the ill-fated period of the dot-com bubble), we expect to make not just more, but a lot more than another university-educated person just because OH WOW, we are programmers and they are **just** business analysts and PMPs.

Can you spell arrogance? Newsflash - for most programming tasks in the enterprise, you don't even need a 4-year degree. Really, is that serious.

Put the time on the grind and build the experience to transition from programming to software engineering (or engineering for that matter) at the senior level. Then you can demand to make much, much, *pero mucho mucho* much more than a business analyst and PMP.

Get it over with - some of us are (or were) overpaid. Period.

---

Rant aside: reasons for a business analyst and/or PMP to make salaries close or similar to programmers that have not yet accrued the necessary time and expertise to be mid/senior software engineers (or that have still not developed expertise in a highly demanded niche area):

A **business analyst** is the liaison between software and systems folks and business people/business processes (which are the ones that justify the existence of your paycheck, not the other way around.) They are the ones responsible for breaking down business processes in methodical, analytical manners, as input amenable for forming requirements, the stuff you work on. They make sure that you spend most of your time programming and not dealing with the minutia of business.

Many of you think business is easy shit. If you really think that's true, God help you.

A **project manager** is the person in charge of juggling multiple projects (whereas you only have to juggle with one or two at the most at any given time.) He's your umbrella, and he's the one that has to do the dirty job most of the remaining unwashed masses don't want to do - to chase people down making sure they do their jobs or removing impediments to your job.

He's the one that will ask you "what are you working on? is what you working on helping moving the project along? do you have problems with your work? what are your obstacles, what do you need? who can give it to you?"...

and then he'll go to others asking the same hard questions, making sure that obstacles are removed, and making sure that you are pulling your weight on the project (if necessary.)

The number one problem I've seen in many failed projects is a lack of PMPs or a disrespect towards PMPs (specially from developers.) It is rare that I see projects fail because of incompetent PMPs, and yet one has to wonder why many programmers are more than eager to say **that** is the case.

Comment: Except that programmers don't demand large salaries just because we're special (no more than anybody else), but because we can get them.  It's not a real common talent, and there's a lot of demand.

Comment: @David - indeed, it is not a common talent... not even among programmers. And that's my point. We have an overabundance of programmers in the enterprise (thanks the dot-com and the java/.net universities). And a lot of programming work on the enterprise is not sophisticated enough to demand rocket-science salaries. Supply and demand combined to simpler requirements (and the fact that we still haven't substantially improved our ways of writing software) tells us then that many of us that special (since many do not have or have developed yet that *rare* talent), and are, ergo, overpaid.

Comment: @David - con't - that is, yes, there is a demand for a rare talent. And yet, many who work in the field don't have it either. That is the sad reality. What makes it worse and sadder is that these same people not only don't know how little they know about programming with quality, but they also do not know the value of their non-programming peers (.ie. business analysts and PMPs). They might be assigned work their peer cannot do, but many of them are just marginally equipped for it. They believe they are special for skills they marginally/poorly have.

Comment: @David - con't - all in all, and I say this as a software engineer and computer scientist, it is petty for people in software to be demand large salary margins over non-programming professionals when the quality of software is generally quite atrocious. Worse still when we typically like to use non-programmers ("the boss, the bizness, etc") as the scapegoat when, by and large, large numbers of programmers (among those who demand large salaries) suck at the very profession they feel quite capable off. There is no excuse for that state of things and there is no justification for their salaries.

Comment: @luis.espinal:  Most people demand the highest pay they can get.  The question is not whether they have a moral right to it (does anybody have a moral right to be paid more than anybody else?), but whether the market is such that they can get them.

Comment: @David - good point.

Comment: your post is too long i stopped reading after the first page.

Comment: @Anonymous Type - I'll try to dumb it down next time.

Comment: @luis, lol, no by all means keep it intelligent, just don't bore me to death.

Answer (score 9):

I'm in finance, and I think the mentality is similar in most non-tech outfits:

**Pay is proportional to career risk**

Barring a complete dismissal of a group or team, the low-level programmers always keep their jobs.  It's the nature of the job, and programmers go into it knowing full well that they are taking zero risk.  If there's a bug, its not their heads on the chopping block.

At higher levels, if something screws up, you are the first to go.  I've had many experiences with a subordinate who made a small typographic error which led to us losing money, and I took the heat for it (not the actual programmer who made the error).

Quite simply, the pay is commensurate with the risk.  Programmers, on the other hand, dont necessarily have any skin in the game, so to speak.

Answer (score 5):

If your question had been "why do X and Y get higher salaries than programmers **at my company**" I might have answered "you may work at the wrong company."

The success of a company in the software business depends more on the abilities of its programmers than anyone else. Companies that don't recognize this are automatically at a disadvantage vs. those that get it. Hiring the best programmers and taking good care of them is your best bet. The difference in the work of the great programmers vs. the rest is enormous; way bigger than the difference in salary they command. But if you insist on underpaying your programmers, you'll get what you pay for.

That said, every other role in the business is important. The great managers have a huge impact. A lot of that is by getting great programmers and keeping them happy. Something similar can be said about business analysis, marketing, sales, testing, and support.

If you are a great programmer and you're not being handsomely rewarded, go somewhere else. Then again, you may not be a great programmer. Unfortunately if you're not great it's hard to see why. If you knew why, you could change and be great, right?

I have been a programmer and I have been a people manager. I worked with a lot of great programmers, but only a few great managers. When I was a manager I was not great, but at least I knew it. My people got more raises than I did, which they deserved.

Answer (score 5):

It has little to do with skills and work, I mean little in the economy is tied to how much people **deserve** to make.

**Deserving to make more money is an ephemeral idea, everyone believes they deserve to make more money.**

While it may not be fair, managers make more money simply because the business owners trust them more.  Managers often get higher salaries, simply so they won't take a new job out of the blue at an inconvenient time.

Answer (score 4):

I think your whole basis for this question is flawed.

Management must be paid more than their subordinates. Seniority in a company is generally based on salary, and there's no way a junior employee can have the means to command their seniors.

Leading people is a specialist skill. Not everyone can be a project manager (PM). The task is more and more difficult as the number of staff increases. In a technical PM role, the PM needs to have a good grasp of the technology to effectively lead - or they will not have the respect and support of their subordinates.

Comment: I think the point of the OP is that not only the really qualified and good managers get higher pay than their subordinates, but (almost) all of them, even the really uncapable ones.

Comment: Another issue: management is a people skill. I don't think a good PM is really needed to be very tech-savvy in order to have the respect and support of his/her team members (neither do I think these team members should really be *subordinates* of the PM). I fully agree with Peopleware in that a good manager works on removing all obstacles in front of the team, and then lets them do their job.

Comment: _Management must be paid more than their subordinates._ Not necessarily. And definitely i don't want to work in a company with this "must" rule.

Comment: I've never found or heard of a company or organisation where it wasn't the case. Though admittedly, my experience is in two very old industries (banking and government).

Comment: @tzhx: I did work for a couple of serious companies where my managers were paid about as much as me, and _less_ than some of my colleagues who were better specialists than me. No, this did not bother any of us, nor made us look at managers as inferiors. Each of us was doing our own job, paying respect to jobs of others — our managers did do evidently sensible work. Team spirit should trump hierarchy, imho.

Comment: @Nikita Barsukov: Ditto.

Comment: Even if that were true for managers with HR responsibilities - and it's not true there - it would certainly not be true for project management. Also, @TZHX: banking and government have very, very different rules than, say, a small software development company.

Comment: @jprete - yes, I know this, which is why I stated where my experience comes from.

Comment: Seriously? "Not everyone can be a PM." Anyone can be a PM. It's just a matter of whether they are actually GOOD at their job... (OK. This comment might not be too helpful)...

Comment: "Management must be paid more than their subordinates."
--> No that is not true. In some countries it is certainly a prevalent attitude, as in some industries. However the more talented you are the more you'll shop around and end up somewhere where this is not the case.

Comment: I completely disagree with this philosophy. A good manager will enable the best performance from his responsibilities. A manager is responsible for people. His people are responsible for other things: maybe a nuclear reactor, maybe shining shoes. Good management of people is often very worthwhile and thus management may be rewarded well; however managing the safety of a nuclear reactor is very worthwhile and may be rewarded better in an organisation.

Comment: @Agile Scout - in an industry without a professional body (such as those in medicine), anyone can be anything. So yes, there are incompetent PMs. There are incompetent programmers. I would suggest that there are many more people in the second group.

Comment: @PP01 - if you've worked in such an industry, you'll understand that managers of technical staff are technical themselves, not just paper pushers.

Comment: @TZHX I actually respect managers; they have a difficult job - but a manager need not be technical. The best managers I've had, actually, were not as technical as I was, however they shielded their staff from the politics of other departments and senior management.

Comment: @PP01 - They need not be, but in the industry you alluded to, they are.

Comment: Management is a role to fulfill, and managers are usually chosen by arbitrary means such as good looks, style, how tall they are etc. Therefore your argument is completely flawed!

Answer (score 4):

In many professions, a core skill is the ability to sell something. And to sell something will, you need to sell yourself. You need the buyer to trust you and value the product or service you provide as much as you intend it to be. This skill is completely transferable to salary negotiations.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through every post, and I dare to say that most of them are trying to compare apples and bananas.

First of all, I believe that someone who says that 'manage is piece of cake' never had to manage anything further than his own schedule. On the other hand, say that 'anyone can code anything' is silly (and is in the wrong forum, for God sake!).

I specially liked rwong and luis.espinal asnwers, although I believe there are other facts that needs to be noticed as well.

I don't believe hierarchy as an answer - not nowadays - although it fit perfectly for the last 10.000 years. We lived for centuries in a society where the higher your profits, the higher your power (and vice-versa). I don't believe it applies for our world, in the way it is (specially in our area).

Back to the main question, I believe that managers usually earn more because they're more valuable to a company not because he's higher on hierarchy, but he's higher because of

- all the knowledge he already gathered from previous experiences (usually programmers have less experience than managers in general)
- for being able to manage several things at once (programmers have one task - or a tasklist - to accomplish, whilst managers have to manage their own tasks
- they're the head contact for the project they manage, and for this reason they're the first 'target' in case something goes wrong. Is easier to lost your job if you're a manager;
  being a developer, you have the 'license to redo something'. That's the 'risk' factor everyone mentioned.
- developers are part of a whole project life cycle. I believe when we talk here of  'programmers' we are also thinking of the testers, technical writers and all other people who are highly important for the project's success.
- and there's something that I saw only in a couple of posts across this topic: leadership. Being a manager is about to know how to be in touch with people, to negotiate, to keep
  everybody motivated, to create synergy when everyone's mood is down.

In my opinion, the leadership factor is the main reason for the higher salaries, because it generates a huge long-term result for the company and for everyone who's around the leader.

BTW, I had only a few experiences as a team leader (far from being a project leader!) and as much I know what a leader does, as much work I realize I have to do.

Edit: Forgot to highlight: communication skills aren't a strong point for most of us, but is a must for a leader. 
Besides, I'd like to share a very good post at Coding Horror, related to good programmers and communication skills -> http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html

Answer (score 3):

Think about it this way, the number of skilled managers is less than the number of skilled programmers, therefore managers are more "valuable" to companies.

Comment: Exactly.  The price of labor isn't immune to the law of supply and demand.

Comment: Except for there are many more skilled managers than skilled developers which invalidates your argument.

Answer (score 3):

That depends how you define 'difficulty'. Even though, I wonder if you do know what Project Management is about and what Business Analysts should be doing. I read much frustration from your question, so I think you have some bad experiences. Never the less, I want to try to answer your question.

Project Managers and Business Analysts are usually 'older' when they fulfill those positions. Where developers start their career very young (around their 20s), most project managers and analysts are near the age of 30 (which already creates a difference in payment just by age alone). They are also the ones that face customer exposing, which means they have to travel onsite, spend hours of torture to listen to the customer (especially when a project goes dead wrong) and enlist their wishes/needs. They have to be careful what they promise and especially within what scope (time-to-deliver). Even though from your perspective that what they do is only documenting, business analysts are educated to analyze the needs for the business, and project managers are guarding the planning of projects.

They act as a firewall between the customer and the developers. A technical perspective is something different than a sales perspective. Most business analysts and project managers are also facing a large variety of customers - they are exposed and therefor have 'leads'. Their network consists out of decision makers and therefor companies prefer to keep people with such networks within reach; after all a sale is a sale.

Regarding difficulty? Start a company, have ten developers and try to manage a project. The headache comes with it for free. Do this for a year and then look at your answer again. For BA's? Go for such an opportunity. Sit down with customers who have an AIX machine from 1974 and the designer of that system is dead/retired/dying/alzeheiming and the developer needs to know if a certain value is generated or has some mystical formula. Try to convince 20 people with a powerpoint about your solution within 3 days time. If documenting was that 'easy', Linux would've pwned the world in 1997 already. Really, try writing a technical white paper every month for non-technical people (the ones that think that Facebook is a revolution in computing).

I am a sales engineer. Which means, I develop but my specialism is for prototypes and demonstrations. And I earn more than a business analyst or a project manager. Not because I have a network (I do, though), but because I left the attitude and focussed more on the business perspective, got myself certified and taught myself some soft skills. And the experience to learn that 'no' is also answer, when it comes to overtime.

Comment: Your whole answer is flawed. Programmers that are at the same age as BA and PM would still get less.

Comment: A waitress also face the customers and get a lot of crap at their face, but it is the chef that get their hands dirty and make what the customer want who will get more at the end of the day.

Comment: Now saying that my whole answer is flawed, is basically telling people that your opinion and experience is the only one that is truth/fact. I am pointing out that your 'fact' is not always truth, as I am experiencing other things.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: **They're more valuable to the company than programmers.**

Why? Because they ensure that projects get completed, even if they're not doing the programming themselves. That means their value (purely in monetary terms to the company) is more than an individual programmer. The company doesn't believe that unmanaged programmers are productive, and therefore valuable... It's only the manager that makes them so.

Sucks, and we may not like it, but that's why the company pays them more.

Their position (as others have pointed out) comes with drawbacks, though: If they fail to get a project completed by a certain time, it's their fault, not the programmers. They shoulder more responsibility, and are **highly** likely to get fired for failing (unless there's some BS company nepotism going on).

So, really, they're not allowed to make mistakes, have more pressure on them, and have a much more volatile job... but don't get confused: **This isn't why they're paid more** -- a company doesn't give a rat's ass how much pressure you're under, how volatile your position is, anything like that. They only care what value you bring to the company. Period.

That's capitalism, folks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many times the Gantt Chart knowledge need to be updated in a year.
But doing programming you need to update yourself with new technologies which will not be so easy with your age.

Learning a new technology need hours of sweat, that if you smart enough to absorb.

The skill gained in years doing programming is not valued much in the current company culture.

Comparing newly graduate programmers salary with one with over 10 years of experience is a bit sad story.

Comparing a new PM with a 10 years PM is a great story, the PM might become Director after 10 years of experience.

So why are still so many people want to learn IT in the university?
I don't understand. Are they been properly informed?

I do not understand how people value the skill nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

I started one month ago with my first project as a PM. Before I worked as a programmer. (by the way, I get the same money as before.)

I found out that being a good PM means being a good programmer with a wide experience. You should be able to go from one team member to another and discuss the problems they have using your practical experience to help them to understand the problems by providing a different point of view. Your task is, besides other, to manage the interfaces. A PM is like a conductor. You can have the best musicians but if you don't have a good conductor who knows how to play the meta-instrument orchestra well, you get only a mess.

The counterpart is the specialist. This is the programmer who is able to solve difficult problems because he has a deep knowledge of the problem domain. These experienced people often also high paid if they are good enough in negotiation. Unfortunately specialists are often nerds and not so interested in money or good in making a good deal...

Answer (score 2):

For the exact same reasons that a CEO can make [263 times](http://www.aflcio.org/corporatewatch/paywatch/pay/index.cfm) as much as their average worker.

Answer (score 2):

Management doesn't always make more than the engineering staff.  The senior level engineering staff should be actively involved with business level analysis and decision making and charting the technical roadmap for the company. When this is the case, the senior technical staff can make quite a bit more than the business managers they work with everyday.

One of the popular myths of business is that the manager should be paid more then the people he/she manages.  IMO, you find this notion more deeply entrenched in buracracies than in functional, agile teams.

To put it another way: compensation is supposed to reflect the value of a person's contribution to the company. There are stellar business managers and average managers, and there are stellar engineers and average enginers.  If you have a stellar engineer that cranks out money making technology and has deep knowledge of the company's technologies, isn't it in the company's best interest to compensate this person more aggresively than an average business manager who happens to be managing this stellar engineer?  What is the opportunity cost of losing that engineering expertise and skill set because you neglected this valuable resource?

Comment: "compensation is supposed to reflect the value of a person's contribution to the company." This defines the upper limit of the possible salary. As for lower limit, I think the explanation in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/45776//45963#45963 is really great, as well as the one in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/45776//45879#45879.

Answer (score 1):

Programmers don't put salary as the highest priority (Assuming it is at a reasonable rate.). Imagine two job offers where one has a higher salary, same time commitment, but requires technical support, strict business hours, dress code, writing user documentation, dealing with legacy code in an antiquated language you were hoping you never had to use again, how much more salary would you require?

Answer (score 1):

If you work for a company that respect programming, math, problem solving, whatever skills, then you may earn more for two things:

- Doing more difficult work
- Taking more responsibility

Just because a Hospital doesn't pay their skilled DBA much (see the example in the first answer) doesn't mean that this is the same in every company.

Comment: -1: A hospital doesn't pay a skilled DBA much? Tell me which one so I know not to go. I don't want my family's medical records compromised or lost.

Answer (score 1):

All right I am slightly surprised with the answers, so here it goes. But before that, I will just like to clarify that I am a Programmer and there is nothing I like more than Programming. That said I have a healthy regard and respect for **competent** PMs and BAs. I realize that many of us resent PMs and BAs because unlike programming it is **possible** to excel in them without the **required** level of competency (office politics, nice suits etc).

However both Project Management and Business Analysis are **critical** components of the software development.

Whenever we think of software development many of us have a tendency to focus only on programming to exclusion of everything else. Yet there is more to it than coding.

First aim of development, which is to create a software which actually addresses and solves customer's issues. This implies first actually figuring out the customer's requirements (as customer may not be really sure what he wants), this is only possible by a detailed analysis of domain in which customer operates and structure of the various artifacts (whether it be people, technical infrastructure or process), and afterwards develop suitable business solution (and its integration with technology) to address those requirements.

Similarly any project of significant size **absolutely** can not work without effective management. Now I don't know how it is in other places, but so far my experience has been that PMs are usually promoted from ranks of programmers, so they do have some idea about what it takes to organize and execute the project.

To summarize both BAs and PMs are [abstraction layer to development](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/DevelopmentAbstraction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Many people said here, that programming is more difficult and that is why it should earn more. That is a very romantic view. The truth is, that in a normal, healthy company the **payment is according to the responsibility**, that means to the **added value** of that person and also the **risk**.

The risk will often be forgotten. Normally if the programmer fails in his hard-to-do job, there might be some increased costs, but nothing more. Not like 10% of the workers will lose their job or something like that. The risk is quite low.

Also I want to disagree with the idea, that most business people earn more. I bet the normal business guy earns less then most Bachelors of Science/Engineering will earn. For example as a undergrad holiday coder I earned nearly the same as some full time *business stuff* workers in the same company.

And last but not least, why is the project manager not an engineer? Normally the project manager is a guy with many years at the front in the topic of the project he manages, meaning in programming jobs it will be an experienced programmer who is the project manager.

Answer (score 1):

There are corporate environments in which either the [**command and control pattern**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/08.html) or the **hub-and-spoke communication pattern** dominates. In these organizations, the manager and the chief communicator are often the same person. This makes the manager [a single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) - any dismal effects of miscommunications or lost-in-translations are amplified. Hence these environments require persons with extensive technical backgrounds as managers to ensure accuracy.

Better organized teams usually appoint a chief communicator to offload this responsibility. Organizations which practice [knowledge management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_management) do not have any single point of failures in communication. In these organizations, the managers and chief communicators solicit for information and facilitate discussions. These information will be captured and processed for internal sharing. A different set of social skills is required.

Likewise, business analysts are often the single-point-of-contact between the customers and the company's technical staff.

Answer (score 1):

This is not always the case. When I worked for Computer Sciences Corporation (CSC), most managers made less than the "people who produced something useful". In the case of CSC, I think this was the case was because the company had been started by a group of programmers.

At the time (1970) there was another software company in LA whose name I forget with an interesting salary schedule. Programmers got paid $25,000/year and support staff got paid $15,000/year. The idea was that if you were the worse programmer there you should not be surprised to get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I've my own little software enterprise and I'm both the programmer and project manager, so I can give you both points of view.

Your initial assumption is not true. Let me write it down:

> Project Management & Software Analysis =
>
> Creating
>   documentation or even creating Gantt
>   chart and asking progress to
>   programmers.

If you really think that's all Project Management and Software Analysis is about, it's no wonder that you think that programming is harder.

But that's a ridiculing, unfair and non-realistic way to define those professions. It concentrates on merely visual aspects, as if the they didn't give value.

How would you feel about this other definition?

> Programming =
>
> Sitting in front of a computer and punching keys.

If programming is defined like that, PM & SA look much more difficult, even by your definition (which isn't correct).

Those professions are better paid because they are, indeed, **more** difficult than programming.

1. They involve dealing with *people*, not machines. People are vastly more difficult to work with, given their non-deterministic nature. The subset called *clients* is specially troublesome.
2. Others have said it, but let me repeat it: responsibility. If a programmer screws up, it's up to the PM to solve the problem. Not just to report it, to *solve* it. It might involve delaying a launch for 2 weeks. Or skipping one feature.
3. The amount of multi-tasking one PM has to do is usually staggering. It's a constant exercise in balance between the team, management, the clients, and the budget. It is *not* easy.
4. It also involves communication "the other way around" - Not only the programmer must report to the PM on the status; the PM is in charge of properly communicating expectations, risks and goals. If some cases they're also in charge of training.
5. Have I mentioned dealing with clients?

If the project managers that you work with just do powerpoints, they are not doing their jobs correctly. And that's sad.

I think you will not really understand why project managers earn more than programmers until you meet a good project manager.

Answer (score 0):

in general the project managers must see the general picture while programmers only do their own specific task,

you can run a successful web business with average programmers but rarely with average managers

if you are a manager you need to do the finance math, you need to work on the personnel issues and trust issues, have a say in the recruitment matters etc.

Answer (score 0):

You think your language/compiler is finicky? Managers deal with self-aware complex-state compilers called programmers, and the good managers even get them to produce software.

Seriously, I like the widget factory vs film school answer, which I think is probably the best answer in thread, but there's a meta-level discussion it doesn't really address: no matter which kind of organization you're building, you're building an organization from material as capricious as *people*, and that's work that's often hard to do well. You can make a solid argument that it's weird that these *positions* often pay better than the programmer's when a significant chunk of analysts and PMs and PHBs are not in fact doing a good job, but the fact is that there is a job out there that involves building organizations that get things done, and it's a skillset that's arguably more difficult to master than building software systems that get things done.

Answer (score 0):

Business Analysts and Project Managers have more access to managers up the chain. That's the main reason why they can get paid more. Not all do. There are also organizations that pay really poorly for business analysts but they risk a very high failure rate due to the most expensive form of bug - a requirements bug.

Programmers who demonstrate the capacity to effectively gather business requirements and or manage a project get paid more than all three of the choices you've listed. It's important to remember that technical services are in service of business needs in most organizations and people tend to trust and value people that they feel understand their needs.

Answer (score 0):

Managing people is harder than managing code. And good managers have the unique ability to find good programmers.

Answer (score -1):

Most companies make the salaries reflect the amount of responsibility you're undertaking, which is a level of risk.  In my experience, a good (project) manager is worth their weight in gold, and increases the productivity of everyone working with them.

On the other hand, paying them just based on the position title is silly, as I've tended to run into more poor (project) managers than good ones.

Answer (score -1):

> For a programmer, a good manager or PM
>   is an umbrella that you don't
>   realize was there until it isn't anymore.
>   Then you're cold, wet and left
>   wondering what the heck happened!

Yes, there is value to a good manager or PM, but I'm not sold on that meaning that a rockstar programmer shouldn't be paid what they're worth, even if that means it's more than the manager. There would be nothing to manage, no product to release if a software company didn't have those incredibly special and talented people releasing fantastic code for them.

I'm currently a development manager at a large retailing company in Canada. Our business is retail, not software development. Unfortunately due to the fact that our programmers, though talented, aren't the "product" that also means that I can't pay them salaries that match productivity or value. I have a set of rules and a hierarchy to abide by with levels, much the same as most other large non-software companies. So, I guess what I'm saying is, it all depends on the business you're in as well.

If you're at a software company, a talented developer IS the product. That company should recognize and pay comparatively.

Comment: -1: *Unfortunately due to the fact that our programmers, though talented, aren't the "product" that also means that I can't pay them salaries that match productivity or value.* - While that may be true, that's an accident of your company. And like @Nikita Barsukov said, I think developer salaries will increasingly become a function of supply and demand rather than a function of a company's reporting structure.

Comment: So if what I'm saying "may be true" is that worthy of a downvote? My recommendation is programmers that want to be stars should work for software companies to avoid letting reporting structure interfere with their true worth!

Answer (score -1):

Because less people has skills to be a project manager or business analyst than programmers. Simply, more good programmer exists than good project managers. I estimate the difference about 10-20 times.

Comment: I estimate that your perception of reality is 10-20 times as irrelevant as how wrong your estimate is.

Comment: I was talking about good project managers, who knows and does the best and learn continuously, not about the people who has a PM badge. They are rare. That's my percetion.

What is your reality?

Comment: @Jeff Swensen: Right again.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can say that programming is automatically much harder than being a good business analyst/PM. I personally don't envy that job position and I think that it has to be pretty difficult, not in terms of technical know-how and sheer logical intellect, but because you have to be able to play both sides of the fence so-to-speak. A business analyst has the unenviable duty of trying to please everyone, but is usually liked by nobody. They have to get the project requirements almost as close to perfect as possible (which is impossible) and be able to make management feel warm and fuzzy about what they're doing and also not piss off the programmers too much. Most of these people get to sit in long, horrible meetings, with tedious corporate types that make you want to gauge your eyes out with a fountain pen, only then to get to talk to a bunch of developers that hate their guts almost instantly. I think the sheer stress of the job is probably worth an extra couple of bucks per week!

These days though, at least in my organization, we got rid of these types of people because often they were a drain on productivity. We adopted more agile methods of development and forced developers to get out there and actually interact with users instead of relying on a third-party to act as a go between and try to pin down every single process in the business and reduce it to a series of impressive looking charts and documents that nobody will ever really read. I'm sure there are really excellent business analyst-type people out there that really know how to handle the situation elegantly but the ones I have worked with looked like they were seconds away from hari cari.

Answer (score -1):

I have thought about this very same thing in the past. It drives me nuts, basically. I came to the conclusion that it has to do with incentives and the principal-agent problem. They are being paid more because they are not supervised, it is a form of efficiency wages. You can read more about this in my blog: http://www.climbingthecorporatebladder.com/who-guards-the-guardian/229

Answer (score -1):

Tricky but valid question.
My school of thought is a little different though I'm a programmer myself.
In the IT field, we have many positions ranging from devs to BA's to PM's to QA's.
Each role has a set of tasks to perform in order to deliver the product.
And each role gets paid by virtue of its importance. Yes, they all have to go hand in hand.
BA's role is important since they understand the specifics of the domain and help the customer to come out with detailed requirements.
Programmers convert these requirement into reality.
Managers look at the bigger picture and ensure that we are shielded from the day to day management related activities which are important from the higher management perspective.
QA's ofcourse ensure that a quality product reaches the customer.

In all this, you can see that we cannot debate who is more important or who does more work. Its just roles that different people need to play.

Also remember that as you grow in an organization, you'll slowly transition from a programmer to a lead dev and so on. This will make you almost equally paid or better paid than a manager. A Programmer is considered as an individual contributor where as a dev lead is managing a team of programmers.

Another hypothetical thought (apologize if my data is incorrect): Have we thought why an eye surgeon gets lesser paid than a say ..orthopedic surgeon? All are important parts of the body to us right?

But at the end of the day, we still do what we do coz we love it!! 
I love getting to work every day and churning out some whacky lines of code!

Comment: I'm going to guess that your entire post is hypothetical.  I have never met a person who works at a software company in which the BA, PM and QA roles are filled as dutifully as you describe them.

Comment: lol I would agree. Seriously, but things would be so much simpler if everybody just did their jobs!

Answer (score -1):

In my world (in my country, or the environment I'm used to be working in), a System Architect and a Project Manager is the same person. Once he designed the system, he should plan the development, do charts, monitor what's happening, etc. He shouldn't get involved into programming.

Right now I am playing this exact role, though the system we're making is rather simple. What I observed when I was hiring, is that most developers (of the ones I came across), to my dismay, can't see the big picture. Hell, they can't even comprehend a whole, but separate, small task.

I am being paid more than them, because they constantly ask me about things they don't understand, or bugs they can't find. And because I have to describe the tasks in such a way, that the programmer wouldn't find anything to understand in a wrong way. I write tons of code, in English. My correspondence is about 20% in size of the total project code size.

I am also the bearer of the responsibility on this project. Every time the project is late, I get to be punished. And I also ensure the final quality of the whole system.

And I think it's fair. I see the big picture, they don't. I tell them what to do, in small tasks, so that in the end something good would come out. I solve the most complicated problems that occur.

If you feel you are in no way worse, then it's the company's fault that you still haven't got a promotion to something bigger than a developer.

A simple developer must be that person, that can do small individual tasks, in a way he is asked to do them. A simple developer must not be that person which understands more, and participates in the project at another level.

It's absolutely not fair if a person who just plans and constantly checks for progress, gets paid more, than those who actually do something for that progress. This exact situation is at the heart of the slowly rotting company.

Comment: -1: *I am being paid more than them, because they constantly ask me about things they don't understand, or bugs they can't find. And because I have to describe the tasks in such a way, that the programmer wouldn't find anything to understand in a wrong way.*: I totally believe you, and you *should* be paid more. Much more in fact. Still, this doesn't speak about most project managers who couldn't do this if their life depended on it.

Answer (score -1):

Project Managers, manage upwards. Programmers manage downwards.

A Programmer's job is to write bug-free code that delights customers as quickly and cheaply as possible. A Programmer manages there code (downwards), thus *if* they do a good job there code is happy. The code does not pay there wages and those that do, do not understand the code.

A Project Manager's job is to predict schedules and help the programmes (e.g. make project run faster) 
A Project Manager spends little time doing anything to help the programmers (managing downwards), and if the project is late they blame the programmer. By isolating the programmer from the upper-management/customers they are able to manage the upper-management/ customers, thus influencing these with the money (managing upwards). They may enrage the programmers, but this does not matter as the programmers are not paying them.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the premise that programming is more difficult than writing documentation.  Programs are read by computers.  Documentation is read by people.  I think most people here would agree that getting a computer to understand what you are trying to say is often far easier than getting a person to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Programmers not only tell computers what to do, they also *decide* what to tell the computer -- that is, designing is part of programming. If someone writing documentation is also deciding what the behavior is that's being documented, then by definition, that person is a programmer that happens to be writing documentation.

Comment: Any fool can write code that a computer can understand.  Good programmers write code that humans can understand.  ~Martin Fowler

Answer (score -1):

While it may be true that on average managers salary is higher than a programmers one, what may be of a personal interest is that some programmer are paid better than some managers. If you want to get a higher salary, you can be a great manager, if you want, but another option can be to become an excellent programmer.

If you really want to understand why managers get more than programmers on average, you should try to understand how economics works, as economics is the science describing prices, money and things like that.

As other replies have already told you, salary (like almost anything in real life economy) is not "fair" in the sense more effort gives you more money, it is a result of free market. If you ask why managers get higher salary then programmers, you should also ask why actors or football players are paid better than scientists or miners.

Answer (score -1):

All business analysts/project managers do not make more than all programmers.

There are other factors which are more important, such as industry/sector, level of domain knowledge, specialization, and the nature of the business you work in.

I know plenty of highly specialized developers who do contract/consulting work and pull in double or more what most BA's do.

It's all about business value, and if you bring that value, you'll get whatever the market can afford to pay.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer: people who knows how to negotiate a better deal often be able to negotiate a better salaries.

Now tell me who is a better negotiator: business analysts or programmers? (I skip project managers because quite a lot of them were programmers one point)

Or put it this way, if those programmers feel that this is not good and continue to work in a company like that, it would be their own problems since they either couldn't change the situation, or they don't know how to express that to who pay them.
Not to mention if the company itself also makes even more money in some cases.

Answer (score -2):

I think the answer is very simple. Managers have to justify their high salaries by placing greater importance on other managers. If they see to it that the managers below them are earning hefty salaries then that ensures they have an even larger salary.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting theory.

Answer (score -3):

Try to translate tech language from developers to business language and explain business language to developers and you will see that it's not much about gant diagrams or writing letters, or drinking coffee in meetings.

And more money do not motivates people for better work (not talking about simply physical work), look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc&feature=feedlik

Comment: I know that programmers don't like when someone say that they work not the most difficult, but it is. And yea, I'm programmer and know what I'm talking about ;)

Answer (score -3):

Programming people, which is what they do, is really hard. Harder than programming machines.

By all means, write code to automate them out of that job and you will have a great deal of money.  I was told that, in seriousness once, and I found out.

[Start here:](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Dunning-Kruger_Syndrome) It's much harder to do that job than you think.  People are hell to work with.

Comment: "Programming people" is a pretty huge overstatement of what real life BAs & PMs do.

Comment: Hey, I did not like it one bit, but people, who pay PM's and coders do not "luck" into the money.  Both are portable skills, they pay what they need to keep them.  That sucked to find out.  I quit and am doing my own thing and the code is how i _relax_.  It's harder.

Comment: @Sugerman: LOL! Totally agree.

Answer (score -3):

My theory is that jobs that are closer to the money get more of the money. (excepting cashiers)

Answer (score -3):

Because bosses let **managers to recruit programmers**, so managers decide programmers' 
salary. 
As a result, candidates' salaries cannot be higher than interviewers'.